# Is that possible to mmap a very big file and using qsort?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, memory, external-sorting

I have to sort a large amount of data that can not fit in memory, and one thing could do this I know is "external sort". But I am wondering is that possible to mmap this large data file, and use 'qsort' as it is a 'normal data array'? If that's feasible, what's the differences with 'external sort'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the file will fit in a contiguous mapping in your address space, you can do this.  If it won't, you can't.

As to the differences:

- if the file *just about* fits, and then you add some more data, the mmap will fail. A normal external sort won't suddenly stop working because you have a little more data.
- if you don't map it with `MAP_PRIVATE`, sorting will mutate the original file. A normal external sort won't (necessarily)
- if you do map it with `MAP_PRIVATE`, you could crash at any time if the VM doesn't have room to duplicate the whole file. Again, a strictly external sort's memory requirements don't scale linearly with the data size.

---

### tl;dr

It is possible, it may fail unpredictably and unrecoverably, you almost certainly shouldn't do it.

Comment: Point 3 cannot happen on a properly configured host. Other data will just be written out to disk or swapped to make room. The only way a crash could happen is if you've enabled overcommit (or left it enabled on a broken system like many default Linux installs) and the kernel can't find anything that's swappable.

Comment: Firstly, you're assuming that overcommit is broken and never appropriate, which is debatable. Even with it off though, `MAP_PRIVATE` makes the mapping copy-on-write on a _page-by-page_ basis: it doesn't know in advance _how many_ pages you'll write, but in this case you'll probably copy the whole file. If the file can't fit in VM (swap + physical), some random write will trigger a page fault which will cause an allocation failure the kernel couldn't predict. Unless `MAP_PRIVATE` should always fail immediately if the kernel can't preallocate space for a full copy?

Comment: A writable `MAP_PRIVATE` commits the whole size of the mapping. If that's not possible, `mmap` will return failure.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that: is this behaviour (`MAP_PRIVATE`/overcommit/`MAP_NORESERVE`) Linux-specific?

Comment: I would consider it just part of the definition of commit accounting: any page that can't be permanently backed by existing (e.g. on-disk) storage must be accounted for as part of the memory commitment. I would also consider overcommit a non-conformant implementation detail of certain implementations, since nowhere in the standards is it specified that "programs that use a lot of memory may randomly crash at any time for no apparent reason". By the way, `MAP_NORESERVE` (Linux-specific) is completely ignored if overcommit is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

It should definitely work if the data fits in address space (almost certainly does on 64-bit machines; might or might not on 32-bit ones), but performance will depend on a lot on the underlying algorithm used by `qsort` and its data locality properties. One issue to consider is whether it's the number of elements that's huge, or whether each element is large on disk. In the latter case, you'd be better off doing the `mmap`, but allocating a separate array of pointers to each element, then sorting the *pointer array* with a comparison function that compares what they point to. This will drastically reduce the number of times data gets moved around in memory, but it will take a little work at the end if you want to store the output back to the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible as long as you have fixed-length records in the file and the file fits within a range of contiguous VM addresses, and in fact this can be considered a naive approach to external sorting. It may not be the fastest algorithm in town, though, since `qsort` implementations will not be tuned for this use case.

Comment: Does it really count as an external sort if you map the whole thing and let page faults take care of the reading/writing?

Comment: @Useless: well, if you take external sorting to mean out-of-core sorting, then it's an external sort.

Comment: But the VM is paging it into physical memory as you sort. Just because those pages are backed by a (non-swap) file doesn't mean qsort magically stops touching memory.

Comment: That's why I said it wouldn't be "the fastest external sort ever", and I admit that's an understatement.

Comment: Agreed, I'm just not sure why the `mmap`d pages don't count as "internal" memory for this purpose: just because the kernel promised to sync them with some block device behind the scenes, doesn't mean they're physically different to pages allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: *Phyically*, I'd say they're very different since they refer to disk pages as well as RAM :)

Comment: I fear this is degenerating into a chat thread, and a Unix/Linux one to boot :-)

Comment: @larsmans: an understatement, but is it a massive understatement? Quicksort is naturally quite cache-friendly, since during the partition you're reading and writing sequentially from only two points (in opposite directions), and it's also cache-oblivious like any divide-and-conquer algorithm that works on sub-ranges of an array. So the OS's file caching should Just Work (TM), in the sense that nearly all the data paged in will actually be used before it's paged out again. It's then down to the OS whether it can also intelligently pre-fetch pages, especially in the backwards direction.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I don't do external sorting on a regular basis, but I know the most popular algorithms are carefully tuned mergesorts. I guess the worst-case O(n lg n) complexity has something to do with that, but I imagine there's other opportunities for optimization.

Comment: @larsmans: indeed. I'm not claiming this is finely tuned, just that I would expect it to be at least somewhat plausible, as opposed to "catastrophically inefficient", like you'd probably get if you tried quicksorting a file by `seek`ing from one end to the other all the time. Seek potentially flushes the write buffer every time, which is going to be a drag even if it only flushes it out of the process, not all the way to disk.